# Magento 2, How to make users to install the plugin via composer

Tags: magento2, composer

In my module, I have created a composer.json file with this code and pushed it to git

```
{
    "name": "lovat/magento2-api",
    "description": "Lovat Api Sales Module for Magento 2",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.2",
        "magento/framework": "101.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Lovat\\Api\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
After I use this command: `composer require lovat/magento2-api`
but I have this error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                  
  Could not find package lovat/magento2-api.  
                                              
  Did you mean one of these?                  
      bower-asset/u2f-api                     
      bower-asset/api                         
      bower-asset/gomc-api                    
      bower-asset/mu.api                      
      bower-asset/goog-api
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a Github repository named (magento2-api) your lovat account(github.com/lovat/). Ignore if you already have it.

   ```
    {
    "name": "lovat/magento2-api",
    "description": "Lovat Api Sales Module for Magento 2",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.2",
        "magento/framework": "101.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Lovat\\Api\\": ""
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. push the code to the github.com/lovat/magento2-api

   ```
    git add . ; git commit -m 'initial commit' ; git push origin master
   ```
3. tag it the same version mention in the composer.json here (1.0.0)

   ```
    git tag 1.0.0 ; git push origin --tags
   ```
4. Open https://packagist.org/packages/submit using your account and submit the github repo URL.

If you already have then just hit the **Update** button or reload page. You should see the change.

E.g. https://packagist.org/packages/lovat/magento2-api

5. ask anyone to run `composer require lovat/magento2-api`

**NOTE**: Make sure to keep the same version number(*"version": "1.0.0",*) mention in the `composer.json` and `git tag x.x.x`. Once you push the tags then packagist will pickup automatically.

Try to change the version in `composer.json` if its not working.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample step for installing your module through composer:

1. Create a git repository for your module
2. Now create a package for your module. Here is the link where you submit your new package:https://packagist.org/packages/submit.

[Here is the link for detail](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html#hosting)

[You can check this git repository as an example](https://packagist.org/packages/sr/module-delivery-date)

Comment: thanks for help! can you tell me why it doesn't work composer require lovat/module-lovat but composer require lovat/module-lovat:dev-master working