# How to build a Composer repository?

Tags: magento2

I want to build a Composer repo which can be integrated with Magento 2 Composer repo.Then my team can use Composer to install the paid extensions with an authentication key.
I have aready read many documents but I still have not got any solution for this.
Hope that someone can give me a solution to do this.
Thank you so much.

Comment: check this answer, it will help you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319363/34579  
 and https://packagist.com/docs/setup

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know packagist.com can do this. But pricing is so expensive. so I can't use their service. :(
I hope somebody can share with me a solution to develop it. :)

Comment: Possibly something like satis? https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#satis

Comment: @tecjam Thanks for your suggestion.